# Show frames per second on Shadow Upgrade

Tags: graphics-card, framerate, nvidia-geforce-experience

I'm using the Shadow Upgrade cloud gaming PC, which is working nicely, but I would like to show an in-game frames per second counter to optimize performance.

I've looked at this list of top five methods to do it, but none of those seem to work on the Shadow PC. The game I'm looking to optimize is Red Alert 1 via the Command & Conquer Remastered collection. I have access to the game through Steam.

Here are the top five options and what results I have from them:

1. In-Game FPS Counter

This doesn't seem to be available in remastered Red Alert.

2. Steam Overlay

I can easily enable the in-game steam overlay and I have enabled the FPS counter, but nonetheless it does not show up

3. AMD Radeon Software

This does not work as the Shadow Upgrade doesn't use an AMD graphics card, but rather an NVIDIA one.

4. NVIDIA GeForce Software

This does not work because the RTX A4500 graphics card doesn't fully support the Geforce Experience software

5. MSI Afterburner

This doesn't work because the RTX A4500 isn't an MSI card

So... any ideas?

Comment: MSI After Burner works with non-MSI cards, I use it with a Gigabyte card (whether or not any kind of FPS overlay with it does though, I don't know).  Have you tried [Fraps](https://fraps.com/)?

Answer (score 0):

I realized that the Steam counter did work. I thought it would be visible only when the Steam overlay was active. However, the counter was actually only visible when the Steam overlay was *not* active.